# How to convert an UnsafeMutablePointer to a Data object

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

How do you convert an UnsafeMutablePointer to a Data object?

```
let bytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 20)
let data: Data = ...?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```swift
let data = Data(bytes: bytes, count: 20)
```

Comment: This accomplishes what was asked, but it does copy the buffer. Depending on the size of the buffer it might make a difference! Use 

Data(bytesNoCopy: bytes, count: 20, deallocator: .custom({ (ptr, size) in
              ptr.deallocate()
            }))

Comment: Agreed. IMHO, copying the buffer is generally safer and 20 bytes is not remotely close to where I’d consider the “no copy” pattern, but your point is well taken. Also [note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780455-init), “If the result is mutated and is not a unique reference, then the `Data` will still follow copy-on-write semantics. In this case, the copy will use its own deallocator. Therefore, it is usually best to only use this initializer when you either enforce immutability with `let` or ensure that no other references to the underlying data are formed.”

Comment: You are absolutely right: One has to be careful about optimization (always understand the implications). Apply when copying MBs / GBs of data or millions of Data structs.